# Display Sweet alert ViewBag Value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, sweetalert

I am developing asp.net core project. Can I Display `ViewBag` value in sweealert?

```
Swal.fire({
    title: "Successfully Added!",
    text: "@ViewBag.OrderNo",
    type: "success",
    confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary',
    buttonsStyling: false,
    ....
})
```

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Chaam, of course you can. Your code seems to be correct. What's the error message you get?

Comment: currently it doesn't display the viewbag value

Comment: I have added screen shot

Comment: Hi @Chaam, it works well in my project, could you please share how do you configure your viewbag value? Did you use asp.net core mvc or razor pages?

Comment: I am using asp.net core razor page. but it doesn't work. I will update My controller

Comment: public JsonResult AddPurchaseOrder([FromBody] PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder)
        {

            ...            
            cMSContext.PurchaseOrders.Add(purchaseOrder);
            cMSContext.SaveChanges();
            string id = purchaseOrder.Id.ToString();
            purchaseOrder.OrderNo = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + id;
            cMSContext.SaveChanges();
             ViewBag.OrderNo = purchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderNo;
         
            return Json(purchaseOrder.Id);
        }

Comment: Hi @Chaam, if you use controller, it is mvc not razor pages. From your code, it returns json not View or Page, so you will not get the ViewBag. Did you hit the `AddPurchaseOrder` method by ajax? And maybe you want to display sweetalert after ajax callback successfully?

Comment: Yes I want to display sweetalert after ajax callback successfully and it hits the AddPurchaseOrder method successfully and save function works successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the sweet alert **after ajax post back**. `ViewBag` does not work like what you want and it is no need.

`ViewBag` is just an object that gets passed to the view when you render the page. It doesn't make any sense to use that with AJAX; your server-side Razor code runs on initial server render only.

The correct way is to add the data to response data.

Change like below:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/home/AddPurchaseOrder",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "Id": 5, "PurchaseOrderNo": "2342342424" }),
        success: function (response) {
            Swal.fire({
                title: "Successfully Added!",
                text: response.orderNo,    //change here...
                icon: 'success',
                confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary',
                buttonsStyling: false
            })
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            //...
        }
    });      
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{        
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddPurchaseOrder([FromBody] PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder) 
    { 
        string id = purchaseOrder.Id.ToString(); 
        purchaseOrder.OrderNo = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + id; 
        //ViewBag.OrderNo = purchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderNo;
        return Json(new { Id= purchaseOrder.Id , OrderNo= purchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderNo }); 
    }
}
```